# How do I pass a react DOM state's information to backend(NodeJS) when a button is invoked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sails.js, axios

I'm using his logic on the frontend, but I'm having some trouble actually receiving that data on the backend. I'm using the Sails.js framework. Any suggestions?

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    // Gathering together the data you want to send to API
    const payload = {
        subject: this.state.subject,
        message: this.state.message,
    };
    this.handleAjaxRequest(payload);
};
```

// Method to send data to the backend
// Making the req -I'm using Axios here.

```
handleAjaxRequest = (payload) => {
    let request = axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/',
        data: payload,
        headers: 'Content-Type: application/json'
    });
```

// Do stuff with the response from your backend.

```
    request.then(response => {
        console.debug(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
};
```

I used to do this using Express and didn't have these problems.
Any help, method, a suggestion is more than welcome :)

Please forgive my ignorance, I'm just here to learn.

Comment: what response are you getting from a server when the request is fired?  try passing header like this, 

headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },

Comment: What's the error you get when you click Submit? Any error in the console? Is the page getting redirected to the wrong location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the first thing I had to do is generate a new restful API using the command `sails generate api data`. In the `package.json` file I set up a proxy that includes the backends endpoint, like this `"proxy": "http://localhost:1337"` - I mean, you don't need to do this, but if you don't then you have to include this URL part on every request. Because it doesn't change, it's pretty convenient to do so.

On the **frontend**, I made a function `sendData()` that takes the necessary data from my previous component (depending on what the user selected) and send that data using `axios` to the **backend** -->

```
sendData = () => {
                const { relYear } = this.props.history.location.state.dev;
                const { relMonth } = this.props.history.location.state.dev;
                const selectedMonth = moment().month(relMonth).format("MM");
                const finalSelect = parseInt(relYear + selectedMonth, 10);


                axios.post('/data', { 'selectedDate' : finalSelect })
                    .then(res => console.log('Data send'))
                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
                }
```

On the **backend** I fetched the data, did the calculations and send back the result to the **frontend** of my app. -->

```
getApiData = () => {
            let apiData = [];
            axios.get('/data')
            .then(res =>  {
            let first = Object.values(res.data.pop()).shift();    // Getting the relevant 'selectedDate'
            apiData.push(first);
            }).catch(err => console.error(err));
            return apiData;            
        }
```